# Putting try and catch in the right place

Tags: python

I have a very simple caching service that caches files on S3. There are times when the file I am trying to cache locally does not exist on AWS S3. As such in one of my files that uses the caching service I prefer to return None if the file i am trying to cache is no found.

However I realize that i will be using the caching service in many other places and as a result I have been told by my peers that `cache.cache_file()` should still raise an error in this case but a simpler one like `FileNotFoundError` that doesn't require the caller to do `if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "404"`

**My Caching Code**

```
import logging
import os
from pathlib import Path
from stat import S_IREAD, S_IRGRP, S_IROTH

from mylib import s3
from mylib.aws.clients import s3_client, s3_resource

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Cache:
    def _is_file_size_equal(self, s3_path_of_file: str, local_path: Path, file_name: str) -> bool:
        bucket, key = s3.deconstruct_s3_url(f"{s3_path_of_file}/{file_name}")
        s3_file_size = s3_resource().Object(bucket, key).content_length
        local_file_size = (local_path / file_name).stat().st_size
        return s3_file_size == local_file_size

    def cache_file(self, s3_path_of_file: str, local_path: Path, file_name: str) -> None:
        bucket, key = s3.deconstruct_s3_url(f"{s3_path_of_file}/{file_name}")
        if not (local_path / file_name).exists() or not self._is_file_size_equal(
            s3_path_of_file, local_path, file_name
        ):
            os.makedirs(local_path, exist_ok=True)
            s3_client().download_file(bucket, key, f"{local_path}/{file_name}")
            os.chmod(local_path / file_name, S_IREAD | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)
        else:
            logger.info("Cached File is Valid!")
```

**My Code that calls the Caching Code**

```
def get_required_stream(environment: str, proxy_key: int) -> Optional[BinaryIO]:
    s3_overview_file_path = f"s3://{TRACK_BUCKET}/{environment}"
    overview_file = f"{some_key}.mv"
    local_path = _cache_directory(environment)
    try:
        cache.cache_file(s3_overview_file_path, local_path, overview_file)
        overview_file_cache = local_path / f"{proxy_key}.mv"
        return overview_file_cache.open("rb")
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "404":
            return None
        else:
            raise
```

**Issue**

Being new to Python I am a little unsure how this would work. I assume it means that my code that calls the caching service especially the except part would look something like this.

```
 except FileNotFoundError:
     return None
```

And in the caching service where i have `s3_client().download_file(bucket, key, f"{local_path}/{file_name}")` I would wrap it with a try and catch ?

While this question probably comes across as trivial and it is I thought I would ask it here anyway since it would be good learning opportunity for me and also understand how to write clean code. I would love suggestions on how I can achieve the desired and if my assumption is wrong?

Comment: I assume `_is_file_size_equal()` could raise the exception, too?

Comment: you can assume that is not possible as there will be some changes to ensure that does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_required_stream(environment: str, proxy_key: int) -> Optional[BinaryIO]:
    s3_overview_file_path = f"s3://{TRACK_BUCKET}/{environment}"
    overview_file = f"{some_key}.mv"
    local_path = _cache_directory(environment)
    try:
        cache.cache_file(s3_overview_file_path, local_path, overview_file)
        overview_file_cache = local_path / f"{proxy_key}.mv"
        return overview_file_cache.open("rb")
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "404":
            exc = FileNotFoundError()
            exc.filename = overview_file_cache
            raise exc
        raise

# then you can use your function like this
try:
    filedesc = get_required_stream(...)
except FileNotFoundError e:
    print(f'{e.filename} not found')
```

Comment: This is quite cool, so not only are you telling the user file not found but you are also telling them the specific file that is not found which can be useful inofrmation!

Comment: you can even create your own exceptions https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want calling code to catch botocore.exceptions.ClientError exception, you could wrap your cache_file method in a try except block and throw a specific exception. I would also go a step further and create a simple custom exception object that wraps botocore.exceptions.ClientError and exposes error_code and error_message from boto exception. That way, caller doesn't have to separately catch FileNotFoundError when file not found and then again botocore.exceptions.ClientError for a different type of error (say permission or some network error). They can just catch the custom exception and further inspect for more details.

```
try:
    //do something
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as ex:
    raise YourCustomS3Exception(ex)   //YourCustomS3Exception needs to handle ex
```

Answer (score 1):

One clean way would be an additional `file_exists()` method in the `Cache` class, so every user of the cache can check before they attempt the actual caching/download. Just like using pythons filesystem/path functions.

An exception can still occur if the file is deleted/becomes unreachable between the `file_exists()` call and the download, but I think in this rare case, the botocore exception is just fine.